# Passing a selectInput() value (a choice between column names) as an axis to ggplot() in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The ggplot just shows a vertical line of values that doesn't change when I try changing the x axis selection. The only thing on the x axis is the word "column" when I try to change the x axis, instead of the values of df$column according to what's selected.

```r
df_variable <- df

df_colnames <- colnames(df)

xaxis_input <- selectInput(
  inputId = "xaxis",
  label = "Feature of Interest",
  choices = df_colnames,
  selected = df_colnames['default']
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DF"),
  xaxis_input,
  plotOutput(
    outputId = "df_plot",
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$df_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- ggplot(data = df) +
      geom_point(aes(x = input$xaxis, y = some_other_col))
    
    return(plot)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input$xaxis` is a string, so you cannot use it directly inside `aes()`.

Try using `aes_string()` instead.

Note that `some_other_col` should also be a string.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$df_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot <- ggplot(data = df) +
      geom_point(aes_string(x = input$xaxis, y = "some_other_col"))

    return(plot)

  })
```

A full working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
df_colnames <- colnames(df)

xaxis_input <- selectInput(
    inputId = "xaxis",
    label = "Feature of Interest",
    choices = df_colnames
)

ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("DF"),
        xaxis_input,
        plotOutput(
        outputId = "df_plot",
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$df_plot <- renderPlot({
        plot <- ggplot(data = df) +
            geom_point(aes_string(x = input$xaxis, y = "Sepal.Width"))
    
        return(plot)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! Great to know.